# R : Storing my lpSolve solution in a list

Tags: r, lpsolve

I'm having trouble storing my lpSolve solution in a `c()` object, when I execute.

```
l=c()
l[1]=lp ("min",f.obj,f.con,f.dir,f.rhs)
```

I get an error:

> unexpected symbol in "l[1]"

Does someone have a clue please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: l <- list(); l <- c(l, lp ("min",f.obj,f.con,f.dir,f.rhs));

Answer (score 0):

In order to add element in a list you need to do like below:

```
l <- list()
l[[1]] <- lp ("min",f.obj,f.con,f.dir,f.rhs)
```

If you want to add in a loop then you can try something like

```
l <- list()
i <- 1
while(<some condition>){
  l[[i]] <- "your lpSolve solution"
  i <- i+1
}
```